# why are the images broken

Tags: html, image, css

I have this [site](http://myposnation.com/) login is test/test all the images are broken....I cant understand why...i am viewing it in firebug and all the images are there....whats the deal...

Comment: Can you post details about the exact symptoms that you're seeing, and the results of your troubleshooting, so that this question would be useful for other visitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Firebug's Net panel you'll see that all your images return a **403 Forbidden** status code:

```
http://myposnation.com/img/th_blue/bk_body.jpg

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2011 17:08:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 344
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=8
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Pics load fine otherwise so my educated guess is that you have an anti-leech stuff out there (probably in your `.htaccess` file) that's testing and rejecting the referrer.

Comment: +1, and there's definitely some weird stuff going on in that .htaccess, `www.myposnation.com` rewrites to `http://myposnation.com/myposnation.com/`

Answer (score 1):

It could be the permissions on the folder? as the images are showing as forbidden

Comment: **EDIT:** I take all that back, that's it: Forbidden images. Maybe a referrer issue or something?

Answer (score 0):

The url() attribute shouldn't have quotes around the path.  Quotes can work but it's not standard.

```
background:#565758 url(../img/bk_login_ver.jpg) no-repeat -5px bottom;
```

Comment: So what's the standard method to link a picture called "foo (1).jpg"?

Comment: That is a good question.  I always rename graphics that have parenthesis like that so I can't provide an honest answer.  For the space you should use %20 to be as ascii-compliant as possible.